# SQL Query in Excel gives "undefined function name" error

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I wrote a SQL query in MS Access that uses the MonthName function.  In access it works flawlessly.  I copied the exact SQL statement into an excel module that I frequently use to query databases.  When I run the query, excel keeps telling me that MonthName is an undefined function name.  If I remove the MonthName portion, the query runs fine.

It seems like I'm missing a reference or something... Right now, I'm referencing Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library 6.0.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks

```
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CustomerName, Employees.EmployeeName, [Policy data revised].EXDT, MonthName(Month([EXDT])) AS expMonth 
          FROM (([Service Team table] 
          INNER JOIN Customers 
          ON [Service Team table].CustID = Customers.CustID) 
          INNER JOIN Employees 
          ON [Service Team table].EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID) 
          INNER JOIN [Policy data revised] 
          ON Customers.CustID = [Policy data revised].CustID 
          WHERE ((([Service Team table].RoleExtension)='2.  Underwriting Assistant') 
          AND (([Policy data revised].EXDT) 
             BETWEEN #" & minExpDt & "# AND #" & maxExpDt & "#)) 
          ORDER BY [Policy data revised].EXDT ASC;"
```

Comment: Just for future reference, what version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MonthName()` function is only available for queries run within an Access application session.  See the *"The following VBA functions won't work when called from a property sheet or used in an SQL statement"* bullet point at [About Microsoft Jet Expression Service sandbox mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-microsoft-jet-expression-service-sandbox-mode-HP001044659.aspx).  Within an Access application session, the db engine can use the expression service to use that sandboxed function.

Since you can't use `MonthName`, try this `Format` expression instead.

```
Format([EXDT], 'mmmm') AS expMonth
```

Comment: provided link is dead :-/

Answer (score 1):

Strange, I just tried the following code in Excel 2010 (64-bit) and it worked for me:

```
Sub foo()
'' Reference: "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 Library"
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\Database1.accdb;"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT MonthName(Month([BookingStart])) FROM Payment_tbl", con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
Debug.Print rst(0).Value
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

### Edit

Further to HansUp's comment, something must have changed between Office 2007 and Office 2010. I ran another test from a 32-bit machine running Office 2010 and the above code run against an Access 2000 .mdb file worked for me using both...

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
```

...and...

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
```

I also checked the `SandBoxMode` registry value under...

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines
```

...and it is `3`, which is the value for "Enabled" (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/introduction-to-access-2010-security-HA010341741.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001107133#_Toc265079117)).

Comment: Interesting.  I took OP's word that it failed.  When I test from Office 2007, I get *"-2147217900 Undefined function 'MonthName' in expression."*  I wonder if the sandbox properties are different with 2010. `Format(date_field, 'mmm')` works, though.  Or `'mmmm'` for full instead of abbreviated month name.

Comment: @HansUp I think you're right that something must have changed with Office 2010. I have updated my answer to elaborate.